# Fetching Array from Json server?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I want to fetch the lattitude and longitude of the `Trip1` array.

This is my android code:
[image: my android code]

JSON:
[image: json format]

Comment: what is your issue can you try your self any sloution ?

Comment: in my android code i am not being able to take out the Trip1 array SfltLat and SfltLong from the json

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you want us to keep guessing what the actual problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your

```
JSONArray msg=tripObjects.getJSONArray("Trips");
JSONArray msg1=tripObjects.getJSONArray("Trip1");
```

with

```
JSONObject msg=tripObjects.getJSONObject("Trips");
JSONArray msg1=msg.getJSONArray("Trip1");
```

And fetch your lat-long by using for loop on your msg1 array's size as below:

```
for(int j=0;j<msg1.length();j++){
     JSONObject msgObject=msg1.getJSONObject(j);
     String lat=msgObject.getString("Sfltlattitude");
     String longi=msgObject.getString("SfltLogitude");
}
```